# jQuery Calculating Animation Amount

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

Alright, so here's my puzzlement: I have a DIV block of images that forms the selector of a gallery. The images are organized in an array of connected URLs, and are not of a consistent size (yay working with archival photos!). 180 images. Animating the DIV to move as the user scrolls through it with a pair of buttons, not an issue. However, is there a way to mathematically calculate the total amount one would have to animate from having the first image at the starting (leftmost) position within the containing DIV to having the final image at the rightmost position of the containing DIV?

The amount animated at any given time is calculated via the width of an individual image; but when I add up the total widths of the images I get 2864px. When I calculate the total amount animated (manually) to move from the beginning to the end, I get 16892px.

The relevant chunk of HTML is here:

```
<div id="galleryContainer" class="shadow-normal" style="overflow: hidden;">
    <div id="selectorContainer" style="overflow: visible;">
        <div id="picSelector" style="position: relative; white-space: nowrap;">
            <script>
                var galleryString = "";
                for (i=0;i<totalPics;i++) {
                    newImg = '<img src="' + picArray[i] + '" id="' + i.toString() + '" onclick="setImage(this)" class="img-rounded img-responsive img-thumbnail" alt="Gallery Image" style="height: 80px; margin: 3px; display: inline; background-color: white;" >';
                    galleryString = galleryString + newImg;
                };
                $('#picSelector').html(galleryString);  
            </script>   
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The doc.ready statement that produces the 2864px calc is in here:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var imgSrc = picArray[0];
    var imgCaption = "Picture 1" + " of " + totalPics.toString();
    $('#picForID').attr("src",imgSrc);
    $('.caption').text(imgCaption);
    $('#0').css({'box-shadow':'5px 5px 2px #888888','background-color':'wheat'});
    // $('#galleryContainer').css('overflow','hidden');
    var totalWidth = 0 + $('#179').position().left + $('#179').width();
    $('#displayCalcs').text(totalWidth.toString());
});
```

Comment: Try adding like a 500ms delay using setTimeout, maybe it has to do with the fact that this is being calculated right when the images are being generated.  You could also try clientWidth of picSelector. I think you'd have to do it like document.getElementById("picSelector").clientWidth

Comment: That seems to have gotten it. The clientWidth returned 1811px (which, I'm guessing, is the visible width of the selector div), but `setTimeout(function () {totalWidth = 0 + $('#179').position().left + $('#179').width(); $('#displayCalcs').text(totalWidth.toString());` returned 18680, which, when I subtract the visible width of the DIV gives 16869, which is very close to what I had as my original animation total. Thanks @JoeSager!

Comment: `setTimeout(function () {totalWidth = 0 + $('#179').position().left + $('#179').width(); $('#displayCalcs').text(totalWidth.toString());}, 500)`, is how the function above should read.